How to configure eclipse to identify custom gradle plugins
├── IDE   
├── plugins
        ├── project-1
        ├── project-2
├── UTILS
    ├── project-3
    ├── project-4
├── WEB
├── spring-boot-project  => refers the one of the plugin from buildSrc 
├── build.gradle
├── buildSrc         => Contains custom gradle plugins
├── gradle
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── local-m2
├── settings.gradle => configuration to include project-1, project-2, project-3 and project-4

In eclipse, each of the projects is checked out as project.
Custom plugin name: my-java-library-convention.gradle
When I try to refresh gradle from eclipse
I get error from spring-boot-project stating plugin my-java-library-convention.gradle is not found.
How do I configure eclipse to understand that buildSrc should be built and added to classpath before building spring-boot-project gradle.
ERROR:
    Build file '<spring-boot-project-path>/build.gradle' line: 2

    Plugin [id: 'my-java-library-convention'] was not found in any of the following sources:

    * Try:
    > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


NOTE: gradle works prefectly when using CLI, using gradle task to build.
I am expecting the spring-boot-project gradle runs without throwing error.

Can you please sshow the exact error?
